# multiselect select - Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am having big troubles get Multiselect to work with my Play 2.0 application.

I have tried different solutions that I found on google, but none works for 2.0.1.

Do you have any guides or tips for getting multi select to work ?

The html...

```
<select multiselect="multiselect" ... name="groupIds[]"> ... </select>
```

The Form

```
class UserAdminForm{

public Long[] groupIds;

}
```

and later in request handler...

```
Form<UserAdminForm> form = uform.bindFromRequest(); // Bam , [NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]
```

Are there any good way of dealing with POST array ?

Comment: what is "<select multiselect='multiselect'...>"?? Don't you mean "<select multiple...>"?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I thing multiselect form helper is a bug in Play 2. Any way, I'd fixed it by renaming the select as @name[]. So you create a template for ex. selectMultiple.scala.html containing this code:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: helper.FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@values = @{ field.indexes.map { v => field("[" + v + "]").value } }

@helper.input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
<select id="@id" name="@(name)[]" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) multiple="multiple">

@args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
    <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
}
@options.map { v =>
<option value="@v._1" @{if(values.contains(Some(v._1))) "selected" else ""} >@v._2</option>
}
</select>
}
```

Having in your model a list for mapping the component, you use this template in your html page like:

```
@selectMultiple(
    myForm("groupsId"),
    myOptions,
    '_label -> "My MultiSelect"          
  )
```

Hoping this help you! (note that I'm using Play for Scala)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template like the following :

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*) (implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@values = @{ field.indexes.map { v => field("[" + v + "]").value } }

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
<select id="@id" name="@name" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) multiple="multiple">
    @options.map { v =>
<option value="@v._1" @{if(values.contains(Some(v._1))) "selected" else ""}>@v._2</option>
    }
 </select>
}
```

You can find this example at [play-framework discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/oiUqGQ8IMCo/2n78_xGk3wEJ)

Answer (score 0):

You error is:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

This means that you are receiving an empty String, which can't be turned into a number. Better mark the field in the Form as optional if it's possible to not get a value in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my example below play 2.2

The options for the multi-select dropdown are in the data HashMap

```
@(data:HashMap[String, HashMap[String,String]])
@import helper._

@select(field = myform("options"), options = data.get("options").toSeq, 
'_label -> "My Options*", '_showConstraints -> false, 'class ->"required", 
'id->"options", 'multiple->"multiple")
```