# Play Scala Framework multiple dropdown values selection

Tags: scala, drop-down-menu, playframework, playframework-2.3, scala-template

In my project I need to show `drop down` field with `multiple items selection(more than one)`. I have done drop down with single selection by using this below code

**userRegisterForm.scala.html**

```
@(userForm: Form[User],languages: Seq[(String, String)])

               @select(
                userForm("languages"),
                languages, 
                '_label -> "Choose Familiar Language", '_default -> "-- Choose Language --",
                '_showConstraints -> false            
            )
```

**What I tried**

I added `'multiple ->"multiple"` in `@select` field

but it showed the all list items in drop down when page loaded.It is not like what I need.I have found this [multiselect select - Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502490/multiselect-select-play-2-0)  answer from internet but I don't know how to implement those approaches in my project as I am a new to `play framework`. So anyone please help me to accomplish this task.

Comment: "but it showed the all list items in drop down when page loaded. It is not like what I need." << I don't understand, questions: 1. what do you see, and 2. what do you want? URLs to examples of what you want will help.

Comment: I need a drop down field with multiple selection.`it showed the all list items in drop down when page loaded` without clicking the drop down field.I need to show drop down items when click the field with multiple selection.

Comment: Do you mean you want the list hidden until you click on the select, then the list gets shown?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML `select` tag doesn't have the capability you're asking for.

I'd use one of the plugins. Examples:

- http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/
- http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
- http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-multiselect

You can copy Play's `select` helper:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html

into your `views` folder and modify it to produce the structure required by the plugin that you choose, include the `.css` and `.js` then there you have it. :)

Comment: I tried      `<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
      </select>`
this example in http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ 
for this I added `helper/select.scala.html` into my view class as you mentioned but I already have some drop downs in my form so I re named this `select.scala.html` into `mulselect.scala.html`.I had added required `.css,.js` files into my `mulselect.scala.html`

Comment: and also I had included `class="selectpicker" multiple` code into `mulselect.scala.html`'s select tag.I had compiled it but it showed `type Messages is not a member of package play.api.i18n` error.

Comment: `D:\test_project>activator compile
[info] Loading project definition from D:\test_project\project
[info] Set current project to scala-crud (in build file:/test_project/)
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to D:\test_project\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] D:\test_project\app\views\mu
lselect.scala.html:1: type Messages is not a member of package play.api.i18n
[error] @**
[error] ^
[error] D:\test_project\app\views\mu`

Comment: `lselect.scala.html:18: type Messages is not a member of package play.api.i18n
[error] <html>
[error]       ^
[error] D:\test_project\app\views\mu
lselect.scala.html:43: type Messages is not a member of package play.api.i18n
[error] </html>
[error]        ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Jul 3, 2015 2:53:39 PM`

Comment: for this `type Messages is not a member of package play.api.i18n` error I removed the `messages: play.api.i18n.Messages` parameter in `mulselect.scala.html`. It was compile fine but the page hided the `drop down field` It only showed the label.

Comment: for messages, your controller needs: `class Foobar @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {` and your view needs: `(implicit messages: Messages)` after your parameter list

Comment: check JS console for any error from the JS file, use inspect with Google to check that the DOM structure is a) correct before JS loaded, and b) correct after JS loaded (it should change as JS transforms it for multiselect)

Comment: I added  `@Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {` in my controller class but it is showing below error 
`[error] D:\user\app\controll
ers\Users.scala:10: ';' expected but '@' found.
[error] object Users  @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Cont
roller  with I18nSupport {
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed`

Comment: `object Users @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)  extends Controller  with I18nSupport {
}`  this is my controller declaration.It is `object` not `class` whether this may be issue.

Comment: thi is my `mulselect.scala.html`
 `@import helper._

@(field: play.api.data.Field, options: Seq[(String,String)], args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)
<html>
<head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-select.css")">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap-select.min.css")">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap-select.js")"></script> 
</head>`

Comment: `@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    @defining( if( htmlArgs.contains('multiple) ) "%s[]".format(name) else name ) { selectName =>
    @defining( ( !field.indexes.isEmpty && htmlArgs.contains('multiple) ) match {
            case true => field.indexes.map( i => field("[%s]".format(i)).value ).flatten.toSet
            case _ => field.value.toSet
    })`

Comment: `{ values =>
        <select id="@id" name="@selectName" @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs) class="selectpicker" multiple> 
            @args.toMap.get('_default).map { defaultValue =>
                <option class="blank" value="">@defaultValue</option>
            }
            @options.map { v =>
                <option value="@v._1" @if(values.contains(v._1)){selected="selected"}>@v._2</option>
            }
        </select>
    }}
}
</body>
</html>`